# How to limit the number of features read in using GeoPandas?

Tags: python, geopandas

I have the following Python code to read my shapefile features into a `GeoDataFrame` using the points `x, y`.

```py
import math
import shapely.geometry
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.ops import nearest_points

absolute_path_to_shapefile = 'c:/test/test1.shp'

gdf1 = gpd.read_file(absolute_path_to_shapefile)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    gdf1, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(gdf1['x'], gdf1['y']))
```

Is there a way to limit the features read in? Some shapefiles have millions of points but I just want to read in the first 100 as proof of concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GeoPandas `read_file()` has a `rows` option to limit the number of rows read (or to use a slice to read specific rows).

```py
import math
import shapely.geometry
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.ops import nearest_points

absolute_path_to_shapefile = 'c:/test/test1.shp'

gdf1 = gpd.read_file(absolute_path_to_shapefile, rows=100)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(gdf1, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(gdf1['x'], gdf1['y']))
```

#### [GeoPandas documentation](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.read_file.html#geopandas.read_file)

> `geopandas.read_file(filename, bbox=None, mask=None, rows=None, **kwargs)`
> Returns a GeoDataFrame from a file or URL.
>
> **Parameters**
> **filename: *str, path object or file-like object***
> Either the absolute or relative path to the file or URL to be opened, or any object with a read() method (such as an open file or StringIO)
>
> **bbox: *tuple | GeoDataFrame or GeoSeries | shapely Geometry, default None***
> Filter features by given bounding box, GeoSeries, GeoDataFrame or a shapely geometry. CRS mis-matches are resolved if given a GeoSeries or GeoDataFrame. Tuple is (minx, miny, maxx, maxy) to match the bounds property of shapely geometry objects. Cannot be used with mask.
>
> **mask: *dict | GeoDataFrame or GeoSeries | shapely Geometry, default None***
> Filter for features that intersect with the given dict-like geojson geometry, GeoSeries, GeoDataFrame or shapely geometry. CRS mis-matches are resolved if given a GeoSeries or GeoDataFrame. Cannot be used with bbox.
>
> **rows: *int or slice, default None***
> Load in specific rows by passing an integer (first n rows) or a slice() object.
>
> **`**kwargs` :**
> Keyword args to be passed to the open or BytesCollection method in the fiona library when opening the file. For more information on possible keywords, type: import fiona; help(fiona.open)
>
> **Returns
>
> `geopandas.GeoDataFrame` or `pandas.DataFrame` :**
> If `ignore_geometry=True` a `pandas.DataFrame` will be returned.

Comment: How do I write this "slice() object" in the code?

Comment: found the slice example here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/396360/44746  `rows=slice(5,10)`